# GCC special optimization options for double precision floating point arithmetics

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, build-process

Do you know which of the GCC optimization flags are the most appropriate to build an application, which uses double floating point and calculates a lot in real-time and it uses **-lm**. A target hardware is two Dual-Xeons with Linux on-board. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dual-Xeon" is not a precise specification of the processors you're targetting - "Xeon" is more a marketing brand name than a specific model.  "Xeon" doesn't even tell you if you're targetting the IA32 or x86-64 architecture.

This is important, because the optimisation can be significantly improved by targetting a specific CPU family.  There are many options [described in the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html); in particular, start with `-march` to generate code for a particular instruction set.

If you are not targetting x86-64, then use `-mfpmath=sse` (if supported by your CPU type) to use SSE instructions for floating point, rather than 387 (this option is the default on x86-64).  Likewise, `-malign-double` can give a speedup (but is only default on x86-64).

Also, if the functions you use in `libmath` are shown as a hotspot when you profile, then recompiling that library with more specific optimisation flags may be of benefit.

Comment: Thank you, -mfpmath=sse has helped. Now my application is about 10 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether it is safe and appropriate for your given application you could consider `-ffast-math`. Please read the warnings on the man page for this before using it though.

I know from experience that it can make quite a difference with programs running numerical simulations. Of course you have to do some sanity checks to make sure the output is not altered.

Comment: gcc 4.1 Optimization Flag docs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea... just -O2 is probably fine

Comment: @Brian: Not sure why you commented with just that link.

Comment: @spudd86: Yes, -O2 is probably fine, hence my answer. I didn't explicitly mention the -O options because even the most cursory inspection of the documentation will reveal these options so I assumed wasn't really what was being asked about. I was simply pointing out a more esoteric option that seemed pertinent to this specific question.

Comment: "Please read the warnings on the man page" made me feel the urge to post a link to something that had such warnings.